# npm use old version of node

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

Currently, when I run npm -v, I have version 9.6.4 installed, and when I run node -v, I have version 18.15.0 installed. However, when I run "npm start" in my projects, it uses version 10.19.0 of node.

I am using NVM and I have no path issues.

I would like that when I run "npm start", it uses the correct version of Node.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Obviously you have path issues... There are at least two different versions of `node` installed on your machine (I'm guessing one from nvm and one from your os).

Comment: I found the issue, I had a version of Node installed in WSL and for some reason Windows was picking up that version. thank's for ur help